# How to change the theme of Google map from Night mode to Standard mode on button click in swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, google-maps, gmsmapview

Need some help regarding the themes of the Google map sdk . 
I have used a JSON file name as style2.json for calling the night mode of google map . 
The theme is changing properly from standard to the night mode . The only issue is i want to reconvert the Night mode map to the standard Map theme with all my placemarkers.
Plese find the attached code

```
do {
            // Set the map style by passing the URL of the local file.
            if let styleURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "style2", withExtension: "json") {
                self.myMapView.mapStyle = try GMSMapStyle(contentsOfFileURL: styleURL)
            } else {
                NSLog("Unable to find style.json")
            }
        } catch {
            NSLog("One or more of the map styles failed to load. \(error)")
        }
```

I have used this code for Button named **Night Mode** i have another button **Day mode**  .What should i do to bring map to standard theme on clicking the day mode ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find out what the standard/default `mapStyle` is by printing its value when night mode is not on.

I did exactly that, and found that it's `nil`, so you just need to set it to `nil`:

```
self.myMapView.mapStyle = nil
```

You should probably save the night style into a property or something, so that you don't have to re-read the file every time you switch to night mode.

Comment: Thanks it worked for me also i tried creating another json file as Standardmap.json and with an empty array it worked for me !!

Comment: and i want convert to Night Mode